# Sorting array based on the object closer to user location

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have set of json data which have store name ,store_lattitude and store_longitude.I want to sort the store in the order closer to user current location.

Below is the sample JSON data:

```
[{"id":"1","store_name":"Nilgiris","store_address":"QWE","store_latitude":"12.929328","store_longitude":"77.605117"},
{"id":"2","store_name":"WallMart","store_address":"ABC","store_latitude":"12.979024","store_longitude":"77.611141"},
{"id":"3","store_name":"Green Mart","store_address":"XYZ","store_latitude":"12.961398","store_longitude":"77.553128"}]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thnaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the latlongs for the user and location off to a function that calculates distance based on the Haversine formula:

In your controller, after loading your data:

```
angular.forEach(results, function(s) {
                        store['dist'] = getDistanceInM(user_lat, user_lon, store['store_latitude'], store['store_longitude']);
})
```

These functions can be either in your controller or in a service:

```
    var getDistanceInM = function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
        var R = 6371;
        var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1);
        var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
        var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + 
            Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) 
            * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        var d = R * c * 1000;
        return parseInt(d, 10);
    };

    var deg2rad = function(deg) {
        return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
    };
```

In your view:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in data.stores | orderBy:'dist'">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also leverage what's already out there with google api:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start

The added benefit is that you can get various measures of distance and can even bring travel time into the mix.  Also it resolves the location from text.  If you can google search the location you don't need to provide long or lat.  2500 reqs daily are free.